# Why is a FPU reset required to prevent a NaN result propagating to next calculation result?

Tags: c++, exception, floating-point, fpu, msvc12

I have a floating point calculation that results in -1.#IND0000 causing a -1.#IND0000 in the subsequent floating point calculation. What would cause this?

The compiler is Visual Studio C++ 2013 18.00 x86. If I use GCC Version 7.4.0 the problem does not occur. As far as I’m aware no FPU interaction is required to reset the state of the FPU.

The code first performs some calculations, converts the values to fixed point. The google test framework uses the method under test. I can mitigate the numeric errors in the calculation (limit the input values, verify the output) but should the subsequent calculation be -1.#INF0000; compiler error?

Minimal Example: I perform a calculation in RunCalcs() whereby, for example, t is zero thereby causing a _SW_ZERODIVIDE. CheckNextCalc() is then called to perform two subsequent calculations that do not depend on the previous result.

Setting FPU_RESET to 1 include a call to _fpreset() after RunCalcs() and before CheckNextCalc() results in val1 being calculated as 0.999981. When FPU_RESET is 0, val1 is -1.#IND0000.

```
#define FPU_RESET 0

#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class CatchFloatEr
{
public:
    void RunCalcs(const float t, const float r, unsigned int& val)
    {
        const float l = 1.0F / t;
        val = static_cast<unsigned int>((l * static_cast<float>(0x10000)) + 0.5f);
    }

    void CheckNextCalc(float& val1, float& val2)
    {
        const float x1 = (2.0f * static_cast<float>(M_PI)) / static_cast<float>(1023);
        val1 = cosf(x1);

        const float x2 = (2.0f * static_cast<float>(M_PI)) / static_cast<float>(1023);
        val2 = cosf(x2);     
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    CatchFloatEr cf;
    for (unsigned int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
    {
        for (unsigned int b = 0; b < 5; b++)
        {
            unsigned int val;
            cf.RunCalcs(0.0F, 0.0F, val);
            //std::cout << a << b << " val = " << val << std::endl;
        }
    }

#if FPU_RESET
    _fpreset();
#endif

    float val1;
    float val2;

    cf.CheckNextCalc(val1, val2);

    std::cout << "val1 = " << val1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "val2 = " << val2 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

### Results

GCC 7.4.0

```
FPU_RESET 0 and 1
g++ -Wall -pg -O0 -pedantic -o app main.cpp
val1 = 0.999981 
val2 = 0.999981

FPU_RESET 0/1
g++ -Wall -pg -O2 -pedantic -o app main.cpp
val1 = 0.999981 
val2 = 0.999981
```

Visual Studio 2013

```
FPU_RESET 0
val1 = -1.#IND    <--- Why would this result in -1.#INF0000
val2 = 0.999981

FPU_RESET 1
val1 = 0.999981 
val2 = 0.999981
```

### Aside

I have been using _statusfp() to read the flag bits:

```
_SW_INEXACT     0x01   inexact (precision)
_SW_UNDERFLOW   0x02   underflow
_SW_OVERFLOW    0x04   overflow
_SW_ZERODIVIDE  0x08   zero divide
_SW_INVALID     0x10   invalid
```

If I unmask the FPU exceptions I seem to get the following catch multiple faults which matches the flags read.

```
STATUS_FLOAT_MULTIPLE_FAULTS     0xC00002B4L
STATUS_FLOAT_MULTIPLE_TRAPS      0xC00002B5L
```

Enabling FP can be done by:

```
_clearfp();
unsigned int currentState = 0U;
_controlfp_s(&currentState, 0U, _MCW_EM);
```

Comment: We need to have a [mre].  [Edit] your question to include enough code so that we can reproduce the error.  Specifically, we should be able to compile from your initial code thru the computation of that first bad cosine value.

Answer (score 2):

`1.f / 0.f` does not result in `NaN`. It results in `inf`. Using it in the subsequent calculations may result in a `NaN` though, as is the case with your `g`.

---

I'll try to demonstrate how the FPU exception state doesn't affect the calculations it does but that it's the state of the individual variables you use that has an effect on the result.  I renamed the variables to `L` and `G` (since `l` and `1` look so similar).

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

std::string excstr(int excepts) {
    static const std::map<int, std::string> names = {
        {FE_DIVBYZERO, "FE_DIVBYZERO"}, {FE_INEXACT, "FE_INEXACT"},
        {FE_INVALID, "FE_INVALID"},     {FE_OVERFLOW, "FE_OVERFLOW"},
        {FE_UNDERFLOW, "FE_UNDERFLOW"},
    };
    std::string rv;
    for(const auto& [mask, txt] : names) {
        if(excepts & mask) {
            if(rv.size()) rv += ", ";
            rv += txt;
        }
    }
    return rv;
}

template<typename T>
void check(const char* txt, const T& value) {
    // taking "value" by-value would not guarantee a bit-perfect copy

    std::cout << std::right << std::setw(13) << txt << " isnan: " << std::left
              << std::setw(5) << std::isnan(value) << " isinf: " << std::setw(5)
              << std::isinf(value) << " value: " << std::right << std::setw(5)
              << value << " ex: " << std::left
              << excstr(std::fetestexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT)) << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;

    float L = 1.f / 0.f;
    check("L=1/0", L);

    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT); // clearing FE_DIVBYZERO

    float G = L * 0.f; // L is inf regardless of the FPU state
    check("G=L*0", G);

    std::feclearexcept(FE_ALL_EXCEPT); // clearing FE_INVALID
    check("cleared?", 0.f);

    static_assert(static_cast<float>(0x10000) == 0x10000.p0);

    // the two below calculations will set FE_INVALID again.

    // casting inf to an unsigned int
    auto lreg = static_cast<unsigned int>((L * 0x10000.p0) + 0.5f);
    check("lreg", lreg);

    // casting NaN to an unsigned int
    auto greg = static_cast<unsigned int>((G * 0x10000.p0) + 0.5f);
    check("greg", greg);

    // the FPU doesn't need a reset to perform
    // even though some exception bits are set:

    float flreg = static_cast<float>(lreg) + 10.f;
    check("flreg", flreg);

    float fgreg = static_cast<float>(greg) + 2.f;
    check("fgreg", fgreg);

    float R = flreg / fgreg;
    check("R=flreg/fgreg", R);
}
```

Output:

```
        L=1/0 isnan: false isinf: true  value:   inf ex: FE_DIVBYZERO
        G=L*0 isnan: true  isinf: false value:  -nan ex: FE_INVALID
     cleared? isnan: false isinf: false value:     0 ex:
         lreg isnan: false isinf: false value:     0 ex: FE_INVALID
         greg isnan: false isinf: false value:     0 ex: FE_INVALID
        flreg isnan: false isinf: false value:    10 ex: FE_INVALID
        fgreg isnan: false isinf: false value:     2 ex: FE_INVALID
R=flreg/fgreg isnan: false isinf: false value:     5 ex: FE_INVALID
```

Comment: In your example the values a linked, new value is derived from previously calculated value. My issue is that the cosine lookup calculation does not use previously calculated values; they are in complete isolation other than using floating point math. Yet the latter value is affected by a previous calculation, which is very odd. And would you be kind enough to clarify what .p0 on the hex address do (using VS 2013 so post C++11 is not fully supported). Thanks.

Comment: @electronpygmy Perhaps you can edit this [godbolt version of my above program](https://godbolt.org/z/i7WVSf) and add the cosine calculations that causes problem and share the link to the resulting program here? The `.p0` is using exponent syntax for hexadecimal floating-point literals (C++17). You can use `static_cast<float>(0x10000)` for pre-C++17 compilers. The `static_assert` I put in the answer was to show that they are equal.

Comment: Ive tried to add other floating point calculations to a new project but I dont see the error. I do not see the problem with GCC. I cant share the entire project. Ive been removing code for a 'minimal reproducible example' but its a complex project. I can repeat the issue; 2 google units tests, one following the other. The first performs the calculations above, the second calculates a cosine lookup table in a loop. [1]. cos(0.006142) = -1.#IND00 [2]. cos(0.006142) = 0.999981. If I use _fpreset() at the end of the first unit test, [1]. cos(0.006142) = 0.999981 [2]. cos(0.006142) = 0.999981

Comment: If you drop the google unit test part and try to just write a small  `main()` function to reproduce the issue, it'll be easier to find out if there's an issue with `VS 2013`, the google unit test framework or something else.